# sequelize create function saves only few fields

Tags: sequelize.js

I have the following code:

```
socket.on("add_upload", function(upload){
    var data = upload.building_data.data;
    var obj = {
        condo_owner                 : getContent(data,"Condo/Owner"),
        address                         : getContent(data,"Address"),
        state_province          : getContent(data,"State/Province"),
        country                         :   getContent(data,"Country"),
        email                               :   getContent(data,"Email"),
        suite                               :   getContent(data,"Resident Suites"),
        mgt_company                 :   getContent(data, "Mgt. Company"),
        telephone                       : getContent(data,"Telephone"),
        billing_account_no  :   getContent(data,"Billing Account #"),
        billing_count               :   getContent(data,"Billing Count"),
        billing_type                :   getContent(data,"Billing Type"),
        calculation_type        :   getContent(data,"Calculation Type"),
        meter_type                  :   getContent(data,"Meter Type"),
        remittance_type         :   getContent(data, "Remittance Type"),
        city                                : getContent(data, "City"),
        postal_code                 : getContent(data, "Zip/Postal Code")
    };
    console.log(obj);
    Uploads.create(upload.upload).then(function(){
        Buildings.create(obj).then(function(){
            socket.emit("add_upload_successfull");
        });
    });
});
```

on console.log it displays all the fields properly, but when I use Create it only displays two fields being saved, where as it should display all fields saved in database. I double checked the fields names and they are correct.

Comment: What fields are being saved? Can you add your sequelize definiton?

Comment: Yes, I found the problem, my Building definition doesn't include all the fields

Answer (score 0):

```
Uploads.create(upload.upload).then(function(){
    Buildings.create(obj).then(function(){
        socket.emit("add_upload_successfull");
    });
});
```

Should this be using either `obj` or `upload.building_data`?  You go through all the trouble of parsing your data content into `obj` then call `Uploads.create` with whatever upload.upload is.  We don't know what `upload.upload` is, all we know is that the data you're parsing is coming from `upload.building_data`

My first thought is simply changing the above to the use the correct object:

```
Uploads.create(obj).then(function(){
    Buildings.create(obj).then(function(){
        socket.emit("add_upload_successfull");
    });
});
```